# C# static SQLConnection

Tags: c#

Shall we reuse an Static SqlConnection in a class,or its better create a instance of it?

```
FactoryDB factory = 
    FactoryDB.GetInstance("sp_select_regional", TipoExecucao.StoredProcedure,
        "portal_sadiaConnectionString");

factory.AutoReset = true;

using (FactoryDB.Conn)
{
    factory.ParametersCount = 1;
    factory.Parameters[0] = 
        FactoryDB.CreateParameter(((IMarcas)Comentario).IDMarca, 
            'I', "@int_id_marca");

    factory.AddParameters();

    foreach (DataRow drFilial in factory.GetData().Rows)
    {
        Regionias filial = new Regionias()
        {
            IDRegional = Convert.ToInt32(drFilial["int_id_regional"]),
            TxtRegional = drFilial["txt_regional"].ToString()
        };

        lstRegional.Add(filial);
    }

    return lstRegional;
}
```

In this example "using" use an static SqlConnection from FactoryDB class,which use SingleTon pattern to get the unique instance of it.

I wonder if is correct to use Connection like this,cause if a want to execute another query in DB,i need to set the "FactoryDB.Conn" propertie to NULL.

Comment: Did you actually try to run this code? It will fail with an `ObjectDisposed` exception, the second time you try to use the `SqlConnection`.

Comment: ive alerady use this,it works fine!The propertie "AutoReset",set the connection to null after its executed.

Comment: In that case it is not a singleton :-)

Comment: no,its singleton!FactoryDB class has private constructor,and we can only acess it class by GetInstance method,which return the unique instance of FactoryDB which is private and readonly!

Comment: @Steven - precisely, well said

Comment: Can you both,define what is single ton?

Comment: In this context your DB connection object property would be singleton if you did not close the encapsulated object every time.  If you ever create > 1 instance, it's not a singleton property any more.  `static` != `singleton`.

Answer (score 12):

Create a new instance of `SqlConnection` every time you need one, and dispose of it as quickly as possible. The underlying connection pooling will be able to manage the physical connections.

If you use a single static connection, things get *very* complicated if you ever need any multi-threading...

EDIT: If you're setting the value to null so it'll get recreated anyway, what's the benefit of having a static variable at all? Just use a local variable:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = CreateConnection())
{
    ...
}
```

Much simpler, no risk of threads trampling on each other.

Comment: Look,in this example,everytime the query is executed,the SqlConnection is set to null,and a new SqlConnection is created automatically,if you need to reuse that.The point is that is static,but there's always a new connection,after a query.

Comment: @user257234 - if you are going to `Dispose` it every time anyway, making it `static` buys you nothing (per Jon's note the physical connection is handled under the covers anyway) and is confusing.

Comment: @user257234: So why bother with the static variable at all?

Comment: There is no benefits to make it static.Actually it is static,cause this class use SingleTon pattern,and to set it on GetInstance method,the Connection needs to be static.

Answer (score 3):

This construct is problematic because the property will get `Dispose`-d on exit from the scope of the `using` statement.  Managing a property where memory ownership is not completely encapsulated is likely to be confusing and bug-prone.

Typically `using` is appropriate where you use a local as in:

```
using (X x = new X())
```

That aside - you can use a `static` if you don't expect multiple threads to hit this code at the same time, or prevent that by locking it.  Otherwise I would use a local instance created via `new` in the `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The value of using a singleton vs an instantiated object is not clear to me when referring to SQL connections.

As has been mentioned before, connection pooling handles the physical connections to the database. Forcibly closing SQL connections every time a query is executed can actually have a performance impact. The most costly portion of most database operations is establishing the communication.

I would have to agree with the other answers in that the best approach is to create a new SqlConnection whenever you are querying, and allow SQL Server to handle the use and re-use of available connections.