# Connection request timed out occurs when program needs to connect to Oracle which runs in multi-thread ways

Tags: c#, oracle, multithreading

I got a strange situation.At first I create a static class which controls the functions connecting with Oracle database,code like this:

```
private static OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
//constructor
static StaticDataBaseWriter()
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;load balancing=false;ha events=false;";
        connection.Open();
    }
```

The database class belongs to Worker class,the class which create Workers Threads named Leader class,each Worker class remains a static database function class.
It runs very well when the thread number belows 3,
when it comes to 4 threads,VS shows Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException:“Connection request timed out”

```
 connection.Open();
```

After trying I am pretty sure about the question is here:
`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(sim1.ThreadSim), mulThreadPara3);`

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(sim1.ThreadSim), mulThreadPara);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(sim1.ThreadSim), mulThreadPara1);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(sim1.ThreadSim), mulThreadPara2);
//ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(sim1.ThreadSim), mulThreadPara3);
```

When I annotate this code,app works well,

When I cancel annotate this ,the Exception occurs.

> My IDE is vs2017 Community,
>
> Oracle version is 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
> Production.

I have no idea about this situation,I just wonder if there is a parameter which needs to be configed.....
Thanks for watching,Looking for your help.

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052214/c-sharp-static-sqlconnection) - _"Create a new instance of SqlConnection every time you need one, and dispose of it as quickly as possible. The underlying connection pooling will be able to manage the physical connections.

**If you use a single static connection, things get very complicated if you ever need any multi-threading**..."_

Comment: Yeap,but I need multiThreading to parallel execute my app,it`s too long to wait for the end.....  It`s the best way to reduce the time........

Comment: So why are you using a static connection?